# React: Infinite Loop with a onClick image that change should change another image src

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an infinite Loop in my React application.

I'm trying to get a previous Image and next Image button. In developement I handle this with an image tag. If my component is loading up the error accures.

Has somebody an idea how I can solve this issue?

Sorry for the spagetti-code I'm trying try and error and there I issued lots of useState's :D.

Thank you in advance!

Some explaining: the "imageArray" does contain an array with all picture names.

The "activeIndex" does contain the active index of the imageArray providing by another component.

The other two useStates should be self explaining :)

```
function FullImage(props) {
  const [imageArray, setImageArray] = [props.imageArray];
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(props.activeIndex);
  const [imageLink, setImageLink] = useState("/uploads/1/" + active + "");
  const [newImageLink, setNewImageLink] = useState(null);

  setNewImageLink("/uploads/1/" + imageArray[activeIndex - 1] + "");

  return (
    <div className="activeImage">
      <img
        src="/img/websrc/prev.png"
        className="prevImage"
        onClick={() => setImageLink(newImageLink)}
      ></img>
      <img src={imageLink} className="mainImage"></img>
      <img src="/img/websrc/next.png" className="nextImage"></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error:

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

The above error occurred in the <FullImage> component:
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a lot of try and error. But for anyone who has the same problem i fixed it by getting a second array with the actual links. Also I was able to reduce my useState's and as well I added a keydown listener to navigate with arrow keys

```
function FullImage(props) {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(props.activeIndex);
  const [imageLink, setImageLink] = useState(
    "/uploads/" + props.pid + "/" + props.active + ""
  );

  const imageArrayWithLinks = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < props.imageArray.length; index++) {
    imageArrayWithLinks.push(
      "/uploads/" + props.pid + "/" + props.imageArray[index]
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", detectKeyDown, true);
  }, []);

  const detectKeyDown = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      setImageLink(imageArrayWithLinks[activeIndex - 1]);
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
    } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      setImageLink(imageArrayWithLinks[activeIndex + 1]);
      setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="activeImage">
      <img
        src="/img/websrc/prev.png"
        className="prevImage"
        onClick={() => {
          setImageLink(imageArrayWithLinks[activeIndex - 1]);
          setActiveIndex(activeIndex - 1);
        }}
      ></img>
      <img src={imageLink} className="mainImage"></img>
      <img
        src="/img/websrc/next.png"
        className="nextImage"
        onClick={() => {
          setImageLink(imageArrayWithLinks[activeIndex + 1]);
          setActiveIndex(activeIndex + 1);
        }}
      ></img>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this will help some people.